# How can i change date format(sed command)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have log file, and here is output:

```
2014109 13:42:17;10.8.0.6;/home/spy/www/index.html;13
```

yearmonthday

I need to change date format -> `2014109` to `20141009`.

I change `Oct` format to `10`, using sed:

```
sed -i 's/Oct/10/g;
```

How can i use sed for day format?

Comment: What or who is providing this date? It may be easier to change the source, because it is using `d` for day number instead of `dd`.

Comment: It's xferlog/vsftpd. And i cant change. I need to change on log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first field is only 7 digits, insert a zero before the last digit:

```
sed -r -i 's/^([0-9]{6})([0-9])\b/\10\2/'
```